# Vim problem in macos, terminal turns blank randomly

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using vim in iterm2 on macos. every few minutes, sometimes hours vim has turned to an (often almost) empty page when returning to that window. I've tried disabling plugins, without effect. I even tried using vim -u NONE and vim turned blank after a while again ... Any ideas? I've also tried nvim with same results ...

[screenshot: this is how the empty vim terminal looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UQqm.png)

[screenshot: what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYrWi.jpg)

Comment: When it's "almost" empty, what does it look like vs what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: it should just be normal vim with my scripts opened, but it looks like the first screenshot, and often the page is just completely blank

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` produce when run in your shell?

Comment: domi@Dominiks-MBP ~ %echo $TERM
xterm-256color